# jsFiddle - logic with select

Tags: knockout.js

I have started a jsFiddle to see if someone can kindly help me to fix 
a logic problem I have in my attempt to use cascanding selects with 
added captions. It is partially working

http://jsfiddle.net/cleytonjordan/4cDdD/4/

I have two selects and would like to add captions to advise the user 
what to do and expect. I have tried using ko.computed as Flo 
sugggested but my logic is still not right.

### THIS IS THE LOGIC

select1 = Poster Select 
select2 = Client Select

One poster can have many clients.

1 - If the view model's POSTER ARRAY LIST is empty I add 'No Posters' 
caption to select1.  I also add a caption to select2 'No Clients' and 
disable both selects

2 - If the view model's POSTER ARRAY LIST has only one item I display 
the current item and no caption

```
         if the selected Poster object has no ClientSite array, I
```

add a caption to select2 'No Clients'

```
         if the selected Poster object has only one item in the
```

ClientSite array, I display the current ClientSite item in select2 and 
disable the select2

```
         if the selected Poster object has a collection of
```

ClientSites, I display 'Select Client' caption in select2

3 - If the view model's POSTER LIST has many items, I display a 
caption in 
in select1 'Select Poster'

```
         if the selected Poster object has no ClientSite array, I
```

to add a caption to select2 'No Clients'

```
         if the selected Poster object has only one item in the
```

ClientSite array, I display the item and disable select2

```
         if the selected Poster object has more than one item in
```

the 
ClientSite array, I display 'Select Client' in select2

When I select an item in select1 that has items in the ClientSite and 
then go back to the caption 'Select Poster', I get an error. I think 
the reason for this is that I am changing from an object to a string 
but select2 is expecting an object.

Please could someone share some light?

Cheers

C

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you select the "Select Poster" value in select1. The selectedPoster observable gets set to undefined. Your second select contains bindings that rely on this value not being null/undefined and hence the error.

A simple fix is to protect the second select from this state by using some computed variables.

```
self.ClientOptions = ko.computed(function() {
    if (self.selectedPoster()) {
        return self.selectedPoster().ClientSite();
    }
    return [];
});

self.ClientOptionsDisabled = ko.computed(function() {
   if (self.selectedPoster()) {
      return !(self.selectedPoster().ClientSite());
   }
   return false;
});
```

And changing your markup

```
<select id="Select2" data-bind="options: ClientOptions, optionsText: 'ClientName'
, optionsCaption:select2OptionsCaption(), value: selectedClient, 
disable: ClientOptionsDisabled"></select>
```

Here's a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/sDt4r/

Hope this helps.